# How to run eval with lockf command?

Tags: shell, eval, flock

I have a command which I run via `eval` as shown below.

```
#! /bin/sh

readonly scr="MYENV=1 sh /tmp/scr.sh"

eval ${scr} -a 1 -b 2
```

Now I want to run the `scr` script with `lockf` utility, so I made the following changes:

```
#! /bin/sh

readonly scr="MYENV=1 sh /tmp/scr.sh"

lockf -k /tmp/f.lock eval ${scr} -a 1 -b 2
```

This throws the following error:

```
lockf: eval: No such file or directory
```

Basically the limitation is the `MYENV=1` which needs to be exported while running the command (thus the use of `eval`).

I'm a beginner in shell programming and am unsure on how to get around this. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

`eval` is a shell builtin. In general using it is discouraged as it is easy to get things wrong.

You probably just need

```
#!/bin/sh
MYENV=1 lockf -k /tmp/f.lock sh /tmp/scr.sh -a 1 -b 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
readonly scr="MYENV=1 sh /tmp/scr.sh"
eval ${scr} -a 1 -b 2
```

Here, you'd probably be better off with a function:

```
scr() {
    MYENV=1 sh /tmp/scr.sh "$@"
}
scr -a 1 -b 2
```

---

That still doesn't help with running it through `lockf`, unless you do something like export the function (in Bash), and then have `lockf` run a shell, so that the function is available.

You could avoid having the awkward assignment word there by using `env` to set the variable. It's an external program, so available for `lockf` too. With the way you store the command earlier:

```
readonly scr="env MYENV=1 sh /tmp/scr.sh"
$scr -a 1 -b 2
# or 
lockf -k /tmp/f.lock $scr -a 1 -b 2
```

But note that that's not a good way to store a command, it'll fail the moment you need to store e.g. a filename with spaces in there. A better way would be to use an array (in Bash/ksh/zsh):

```
scr=(env MYENV=1 sh /tmp/scr.sh)
"${scr[@]}" -a 1 -b 2
# or 
lockf -k /tmp/f.lock "${scr[@]}" -a 1 -b 2
```

See: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)